# Approximating a measurable set with measurable sets in a smaller sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E$ be a non-empty set and let $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ be two sigma-algebras on $E$, with $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{E}$. Let also $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathcal{E}$.

**Question.** Under which conditions the following statement is true?

> For every $A \in \mathcal{E}$ and every $\epsilon >0$ there exist two sets $B,C \in \mathcal{F}$ such that
> $$ B \subseteq A \subseteq C \qquad\text{and}\qquad \mu(C\setminus B) = \mu(C) - \mu(B) < \epsilon$$

Comment: EIther I miss something or it's trivially false. Consider segment $[0,1]$ with $\mu[a,b] = b - a$. Let  $P$ be trivial partition (only set $[0,1]$) and $Q$ be partition into sets $[0, \frac 12]$ and $[\frac 12, 1]$. Then for $A=[0, \frac 12]$ such $B$ and $C$ don't exist (we must have $B=\emptyset$ and $C=[0,1]$, but $\mu(C) - \mu(B)=1$).

Comment: @Dmitry you are right. The fact is, I desperately need a result like this. Do you know which further hypotheses could I add to make it true? Maybe the sigma-algebras to be reacher than those generated by finite partitions?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I can share random thoughts if you are interested: 1) In some sense, you want $F$ to be "dense" wrt $E$. e.g. if you construct $F$ based on rational intervals, this property should hold (I think) when $E$ is based on real intervals. 2) Maybe you are interested in some specific constructions? E.g. what if you construct $\sigma$-algebras similarly to how it's done for [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure#Construction_of_the_Lebesgue_measure)?

Comment: Random thoughts are absolutely welcome: thank you so much. I actually have a filtration (sequence of increasing sigma-algebras) converging towards a sigma-algebra where the measure is defined, and I would be happy just if the result was true eventually. However, unfortunately, the sigma algebras are all generated by finite partitions of $E$. This might be a problem. Thank you for your ideas, though. They will be very usefulz

Comment: Another thought. For every $A$, we define $B_n$ and $C_n$ so that $B_n \subseteq B_{n+1}$, $C_{n+1} \subseteq C_n$, $B_n \subseteq A \subseteq C_n$ and $\mu(C_n) - \mu(B_n) < \frac 1n$. We define $B = \cup B_n$ and $C = \cap C_n$ (they still belong to $F$). Note that $\mu(B) = \mu(C)$ and $B \subseteq A \subseteq C$. Therefore, we have $\mu(A \setminus B) = \mu(C \setminus A) = 0$. In other words, $E$ can "split" $F$ by only "separationing" sets of measure $0$. I think this condition (if formalized) might suffice.

Comment: @Dmitry thank you for your ideas. I think I have rephrased the problem in a way that could work, but it changes the question completely, so I shall write another question ad hoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose an example showing that in such generality the problem is not trivial.

Consider $E:=\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{F}:=$ Borel or Lebesgue measurable sets and $\mathcal{E}:=\sigma(\mathcal{F}\cup \{V\})$ where $V$ is some non Lebesgue measurable subset of the real line. We define $\mu$ to be any extension of  Lebesgue measure to $\mathcal{E}$ (in fact, we can assign any value to $\mu(V)$ between the inner and outer Lebesgue measures of $V$). Then, for this example, your condition does not hold.